# PHP. How to click on a list item so it appears in table?

Tags: php, html, sql

I have the following unordered list:

```
foreach($result as $res){
        echo'<ul>
                <li>'.$res[0].', funding: '.(($res[1]<=0)?'sufficient':$res[1]).'<br>'.$res[2].'</li>
             </ul>';
    }
```

How can I click/select one ore more of the list items. So they appears in a table on the same page?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "Click/Select list items and have them appear in a table" ? Do you have a list and want to move selected items over into a all ready defined table or what?

Comment: a possibility is to use javascript and the onclick event. then copy the text from the list into the table

Comment: When i load the page. There should be the unordered list with data and the tabel with nothing in it. When i click one or more of the list items. The data should also appear in the table, without removing anything from the unordered list.